# mcrypt_decrypt - strange padding (not default, not with null)

Tags: php, cryptography, padding

I'm trying to use symmetric decryption with code as follow:

```
$encrypted = base64_decode($encryptedBase64String);
$returnText = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, iv);
```

And I meet strange result (as nobody questioned).
I don't know why method `mcrypt_decrypt` returns decrypted text with padding fulfilled with byte values which equals number of padded chars. According to the php manual the method should pad its return with zero values bytes.

To clarify it I have placed two examples below:

[Above call of `mcrypt_decrypt` pads return string to length of 32]

**example 1**

> plainText = 'text'
>
> length of 'text' is 4, so size of padding is 28 chars (32 - 4)

So I receive returnText as:

```
{\116\101\120\116\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28\28}
```

**example 2**

> '12345678901234567890'
>
> length = 20

```
{\49\50\51\52\53\54\55\56\57\48\49\50\51\52\53\54\55\56\57\48\12\12\12\12\12\12\12\12\12\12\12\12}
```

What can I do to change it? I have problem with removing padding with method rtrim("\0") since padding is not by null.

Comment: Note that Rijndael-256 is not the algorithm that has been standardized as AES, for compatability you should try and use Rijndael-128, possibly with 256 bit keys (128 bit is the block size, not the key size of AES).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the string to be encrypted is not the right length, `mcrypt_encrypt` will pad it with `\0`s.  Whoever encrypted the string you are decrypting added their own padding first, so PHP didn't have to pad it.  This type of padding is called [`PKCS7 padding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding).

To remove it you can try something like this (stolen from [here](https://gist.github.com/1077723)):

```
$strPad = ord($returnText[strlen($returnText)-1]);
$returnText = substr($returnText, 0, -$strPad);
```

Comment: Now it works as I expected! Smart code snippet and useful link to knowledge about padding systems. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I use this type of padding in my own code, so I recognized it :P